# How do I distribute my C++ Allegro 5 programs so that they work on computers without Allegro installed?

Tags: c++, deployment, allegro

I am making a game that I do not want my users to have to download anything but the game folder and be able to simply double click and run. I can compile my code in OSX without Xcode just fine but when I try run the game on another computer using OSX it will not run. What do I need to include for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link has a thorough tutorial on how to setup your Xcode so that the resulting .app is ready for distribution.

http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=OSX,_Xcode_4,_Framework

Comment: It was great up until the point where it couldn't find allegro5/allegro.h